# How to add Auto Numbring to rows in grid?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using a grid in `wxpython`, I'm getting the data from `SQL` query.
I want to add another column which will be the number of row. Assume that the `SQL` query can not be modified.

if there are 4 rows values will be  1,2,3,4

if there are 3 rows values will be 1,2,3

To clerfy lets use this example of simple PhoneBook:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578676-a-phone-book-gui-built-in-wxpython-connected-to-da/

There are 4 columns there:

```
     self.grid_1.CreateGrid(r, 4)#this is to create the grid with same rows as database
    self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(0, _("ID"))
    self.grid_1.SetColSize(0, 12)
    self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(1, _("NAME"))
    self.grid_1.SetColSize(1, 150)
    self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(2, _("SURNAME"))
    self.grid_1.SetColSize(2, 150)
    self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(3, _("NUMBER"))
```

Now assume that `ID` is a column that the values are not given from the database but the client has to assigne row numbers...

suppose the `SQL` gives:

```
NAME Surname Number
A       V      55
B       C      45
```

How would you change the code to generate auto row number:

```
ID    NAME Surname Number
1      A       V      55
2      B       C      45
```

Comment: The grid rows are already numbered. Why do you want the numbers in the cells too?

Comment: I used this templete as an example to solve my problem. Assume for example SQL gives 20 rows. I want to present auto numbring for them.